# Mongo $match parent having a doubly nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to $match against Mongo elements for double nested array:

```
  {
    $match: {
      "cards.[].listings.0": {
        $exists: true,
      },
    },
  },
```

I'm looking for parent documents which have `cards` which also have `listings`.

I've seen something like the above syntax before, although I'm not sure what this syntax is called or if it's possible to use it for double-nested arrays.

Comment: Could you provide a sample doc as well please ? You could also have double condition in $match, something like 
`$match: {
      "cards": { $exists: true },
      "cards.listings": { $exists: true }
    }
  } `
but i m not sure about the structure of your documents in the collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside an aggregation pipeline simply use:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "cards.listings.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lncnhdOkfxJ)

Comment: Oh! ::facepalm::